# tkinter user input widget to xlsx

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, widget, user-input, xlsxwriter

How do I write user input from tkinter entry widget to xlsx?
Should I be using a different module?

```
from tkinter import *
import xlsxwriter

def output():

    c = Toplevel(root)
    c.title =("Main")
    c.geometry =('')


    e= Entry(c, width=20).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W, padx=10)
    l=Label(c, text="Current Value").grid(row = 0, column=0, sticky=W, padx=10)


    e2 = Entry(c, width=20).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W, padx=10)
    l2= Label(c, text="New Value").grid(row = 1, column=0, sticky=W, padx=10)
    b=Button(c, text="Submit",command= write_to_xlsx).grid(row= 1, column=2, sticky=E, padx=10)



def write_to_xlsx():


    workbook =xlsxwriter.Workbook('tkintertest18.xlsx')

    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    worksheet.write_string('C1', 'e2.get()')

    workbook.close()


root = Tk()
root.title("Main Menu")
root.geometry('400x400+230+130')

Button(root, text="1", command=output).grid(row =0, column= 2)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should almost **always** use a class when tkinter is involved. So here is a working prototype of your code above. There were multiple problems. One is that when you slap `grid` next to your widgets instead of putting them on a new line, `grid` returns None, not the object. Implementing the app as a class enables the other functions to access the GUI components (in this case self.e2). Another error was you had single-quoted the 'e2.get()' call, which is technically a string. So removing the quotes fixes that. There may have been other things...

```
import xlsxwriter

class XLwriter:

    def __init__(self):

        c = Toplevel(root)
        c.title =("Main")
        c.geometry =('')


        self.e= Entry(c, width=20).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W, padx=10)
        self.l=Label(c, text="Current Value").grid(row = 0, column=0, sticky=W, padx=10)


        self.e2 = Entry(c, width=20)
        self.e2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W, padx=10)
        self.l2= Label(c, text="New Value").grid(row = 1, column=0, sticky=W, padx=10)
        self.b=Button(c, text="Submit",command=self.write_to_xlsx).grid(row= 1, column=2, sticky=E, padx=10)



    def write_to_xlsx(self):


        workbook =xlsxwriter.Workbook('tkintertest18.xlsx')

        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

        worksheet.write_string('C1', self.e2.get())

        workbook.close()


root = Tk()
root.title("Main Menu")
root.geometry('400x400+230+130')
app = XLwriter()
#Button(root, text="1", command=output).grid(row =0, column= 2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `You should almost always use a class when tkinter is involved`. Could you explain this statement. I have a tkinter app I wrote with over 600 lines of code all in functions and variables, no class was used and it works fine. (I do use classes for OOP style programming) Just want to know the reasoning behind your statement.

Comment: Some reasons for using classes is to avoid the use of global variables (bad practice), leverage inheritance of objects, make the code more portable (if you create a class, you might well be able to create a module that is reusable for other projects), among others.

Comment: If you add that statement to your answer it will help others who drop by and the OP to understand why rather than just telling them, I am  paraphrasing here "just do it this way".

Comment: Thank you both @Ron Norris and @@Sierra Mountain Tech. It is nice to see two adaptations and I appreciate the explanation on why class use is important.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing that Ron already provided you with a class to perform this task I will respond with the non-class method of doing this to more closely reflect the current code you have.

Keep in mind that with `xlsxwriter` there is not a way to read from the spreadsheet so for the entry field you have that is labeled as `"Current Value"` you will need to use a different excel library to fill that field with data from the spreadsheet.

Make sure if you are going to interact with a widget that you do not use the geometry manager directly with the creation of the widget. This will return None to anything trying to interact with it. Instead on the next line after you have created the widget you can use the widget variable name and then your geometry manager of choice(`grid(), pack(), place()`). This will allow us to interact with the widget without the issue of None being returned by the geometry manager.

In order for you to be able to interact with `e2` outside of the `output()` function you will need to assign e2 to the `global` namespace. You can do this by simply adding `global e2` inside your `output()` function.

Note: The use of global is best avoided whenever possible this is one compelling reason to use a more Object Oriented Programing method (class) as the use of global is not needed when using class attributes.

```
from tkinter import *
import xlsxwriter

root = Tk()
root.title("Main Menu")
#root.geometry('400x400+230+130')

def output():
    global e2
    c = Toplevel(root)
    c.title = ("Main")

    e = Entry(c, width = 20)
    e.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W, padx = 10)
    l = Label(c, text = "Current Value")
    l.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W, padx = 10)

    e2 = Entry(c, width=20)
    e2.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W, padx = 10)
    l2 = Label(c, text = "New Value")
    l2.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W, padx = 10)
    b = Button(c, text = "Submit",command = write_to_xlsx)
    b.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = E, padx = 10)

def write_to_xlsx():
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('tkintertest18.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet.write_string('C1', e2.get())
    workbook.close()

btn = Button(root, text = "1", command = output)
btn.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Ron Norris why does the entry field not capture the data? I get the Line 28 AttributeError: 'NonType' object has no attribute get

Comment: Oops! Thanks @Sierra Mountain Tech. I've now got the problem in a new post.